# How to retrieve all the comments for a post using related names?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to create a comment page for a blog-style site that will list all of the previous comments for a single related post.

I am having trouble figuring out how to structure the view to get what I'm looking for.  I have been trying to use related names to get the data but am not sure if that is the right method.

Here are my models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    content = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pics', blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')
```

And here is my view:

```
class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'home/comment-form.html'
    fields = ['comment',]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CommentCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['post'] = Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        comments = Post.comments.all()
        context['comments'] = comments
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.post = Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I have been trying a bunch of different things.  The above is just my latest attempt.  When I try to run this one I get a `'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'` error.

I don't know if I need to run a `get_queryset()` function or maybe call a `queryset` at the beginning of the view?

Know this is probably a very basic issue but I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to pass `comments` to template, you can simply use:

```
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    {{ comment.comment }}
{% endfor %}
```

It is possible because you already defined `related_name='comments'` in `Comment` model.

Comment: Ahh OK that makes complete sense.  All working now, thank you! Figured there had to be a pretty simple fix.

Answer (score 1):

To get the comments, you can use a `filter()`

```
Class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'home/comment-form.html'
    fields = ['comment',]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CommentCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['post'] = post
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
        context['comments'] = comments
        return context
```